Issue with Logo Container Margin Disappearing After Webpage Refresh
Description: I’m encountering an issue with the marginTop of my logo container in a React application. After refreshing the webpage, the marginTop value seems to disappear, causing layout problems. Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useGlobalContext } from './context/globalContext';
import bg from './img/bg.png';
import logo from './img/logoSWB.svg';

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const { handleLogin } = useGlobalContext();

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      await handleLogin(email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles.background}>
      <div style={styles.logoContainer}>
        <img src={logo} alt="Logo" style={styles.logo} />
      </div>
      {/* Rest of the login form */}
    </div>
  );
};

const styles = {
  background: {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    background: `url(${bg})`,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    zIndex: -1,
  },
  logoContainer: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: '50px', // Issue: marginTop disappears after refreshing
  },
  // Other styles...
};

export default Login;

Problem:
The marginTop value for the logo container works initially but disappears after a page refresh.
I’ve checked for conflicting styles and inspected the computed styles, but I can’t find the root cause.
I want the marginTop to persist even after refreshing the page.
